How to add additional Indentation for the PrimeVue Tree component for clear parent-child difference?
I use the Tree component from the PrimeVue library to display some parent-child relations. I can obtain the data correctly but for some reason, The data shown does not contain sufficient indentation to distinguish clearly the parent and child.
Both parent and child almost appear in the same line due to which I am unable to clearly identify the parent and its children when expanded. How to add additional indentation or padding when displaying the parent-child relation in PrimeVue Tree?
I have the following code in the pages/Test.vue page of my Nuxt 3 application:
<template>
  <Tree :value="dummyTreeData">
    <template #default="slotProps">
        <b>{{ slotProps.node.label }}</b>
    </template>
  </Tree>
</template>
  
<script setup>
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";
import Tree from "primevue/tree";

const dummyTreeData = ref([
  {
    key: "0",
    label: "Documents",
    data: "Documents Folder",
    icon: "ic:round-folder",
    children: [
      {
        key: "0-0",
        label: "Work",
        data: "Work Folder",
        icon: "fluent:movies-and-tv-16-filled",
        children: [
          {
            key: "0-0-0",
            label: "Expenses.doc",
            icon: "fluent:movies-and-tv-16-filled",
            data: "Expenses Document",
          },
          {
            key: "0-0-1",
            label: "Resume.doc",
            icon: "fluent:movies-and-tv-16-filled",
            data: "Resume Document",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        key: "0-1",
        label: "Home",
        data: "Home Folder",
        icon: "mdi:home-outline",
        children: [
          {
            key: "0-1-0",
            label: "Invoices.txt",
            icon: "fluent:movies-and-tv-16-filled",
            data: "Invoices for this month",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    key: "1",
    label: "Events",
    data: "Events Folder",
    icon: "material-symbols:emoji-events",
    children: [
      {
        key: "1-0",
        label: "Meeting",
        icon: "fluent:movies-and-tv-16-filled",
        data: "Meeting",
      },
      {
        key: "1-1",
        label: "Product Launch",
        icon: "fluent:movies-and-tv-16-filled",
        data: "Product Launch",
      },
      {
        key: "1-2",
        label: "Report Review",
        icon: "fluent:movies-and-tv-16-filled",
        data: "Report Review",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    label: "Movies",
    data: "Movies Folder",
    icon: "fluent:movies-and-tv-16-filled",
    children: [
      {
        key: "2-0",
        icon: "fluent:movies-and-tv-16-filled",
        label: "Al Pacino",
        data: "Pacino Movies",
        children: [
          {
            key: "2-0-0",
            label: "Scarface",
            icon: "fluent:movies-and-tv-16-filled",
            data: "Scarface Movie",
          },
          {
            key: "2-0-1",
            label: "Serpico",
            icon: "fluent:movies-and-tv-16-filled",
            data: "Serpico Movie",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        key: "2-1",
        label: "Robert De Niro",
        icon: "pi pi-fw pi-star",
        data: "De Niro Movies",
        children: [
          {
            key: "2-1-0",
            label: "Goodfellas",
            icon: "arcticons:movies-anywhere",
            data: "Goodfellas Movie",
          },
          {
            key: "2-1-1",
            label: "Untouchables",
            icon: "arcticons:vi-movies-and-tv",
            data: "Untouchables Movie",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
</script>

I get the data within PrimeVue Tree as:

As per the official documentation here: https://primevue.org/tree/#basic, it seems to have a clear distinguishing and can see the parent-child relation easily and clearly. I tried adding different themes and settings but nothing seemed to work for me.
Is there anything I can do to add the additional indentation?

Since the default PrimeVue tree has decent indentation, it must be your own app's custom CSS that is affecting it.  You'll need to use your browser's DOM inspector to figure it out and/or add your styling/customization code to your question since without it the issue is not reproducible.

Just using the DOM inspector on the PrimeVue documentation page, the child elements have padding on a <ul> element with styling applied as .p-tree .p-treenode-children { padding: 0 0 0 1rem; }.  When this style is toggled off, the child and parent elements align like in your screenshot.  Check your own app's DOM and see if this is applied or overridden by something else
